# Extract HTML from URL

Tags: java, html, string, url, extract

I'm using [Boilerpipe](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) to extract text from url, using this code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/some-location/index.html");
String text = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(url);
```

the String `text` contains just the text of the html page, but I need to extract to whole html code from it.

Is there anyone who used this library and knows how to extract the HTML code?

You can check the [demo page](http://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/) for more info on the library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For something as simple as this you don't really need an external library:

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
 InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
 String line = null;
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
 while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
   sb.append(line);
 }
 String htmlContent = sb.toString();
```

Comment: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `KeepEverythingExtractor` instead of the `ArticleExtractor`.

But this is using the wrong tool for the wrong job. What you want is just to download the HTML content of a URL (right?), not extract content. So why use a content extractor?

Comment: KeepEverythingExtractor is not returning the HTML code, it returns the full text on the HTML page (links, ...)

Answer (score 1):

With Java 7 and a trick of Scanner, you can do the following:

```java
public static String toHtmlString(URL url) throws IOException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(url, "The url cannot be null.");
    try (InputStream is = url.openStream(); Scanner sc = new Scanner(is)) {
        sc.useDelimiter("\\A");
        if (sc.hasNext()) {
            return sc.next();
        } else {
            return null; // or empty
        }
    }
}
```